# Índice de datos Long en Array (Java) - Problema de lógica

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una práctica con índices long en Java para este ejercicio de lógica. ¿Alguna idea cómo plantearlo con datos tipo long?, ya que el problema de lógica pide un índice muy alto. (En mi ejercicio traté de incluir y pasar todo a long, pero no me está saliendo). ¿Alguna forma adicional de cómo hacerlo además de arrays?

Ejercicio:

Una computadora comienza imprimiendo los números 1, 2 y 3.

Luego continúa imprimiendo sin parar la suma de los últimos 3 números que imprimió: 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, ..

¿Cuáles son los últimos 4 dígitos del número impreso en la posición 2020202020202020?

Por ejemplo, en la posición 30, está impreso el número 45152016 que termina en 2016.

Mi código en Java con datos int (funcionando) es:

```
    public class Puzzle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int TAM_ARRAY = 8;
        int[] resultado = new int[TAM_ARRAY + 1];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < TAM_ARRAY; i++) {// 0 //1 //2 //3
            resultado[i] = i + 1; // 0 //2 //3 //4 FALL

            if (i >= 3) {
                resultado[i] = resultado[i - 1] + resultado[i - 2] + resultado[i - 3];
            }

        }

        System.out.println(resultado[TAM_ARRAY-1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Es obligatorio que sea un array[] o puede ser un ArrayList?

Comment: Con que seria mas eficiente hacerlo @crrlos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ordago creo que tu codigo tiene un problema en los valores en el array de datos por la condición if (num < 3), puedes controlar con el valor de la posicion 30 que no devuelve el resultado esperado (2016) iniciando con esos valores del array datos.
Puedes corregirlo cambiando el array de datos asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] datos = new int[] {
       0,1,2
    };
    Long num = 2020202020202020L % 124000L;
    int resultado = 0;
    if (num < 3) {
        resultado = datos[num.intValue()];
    } else {
        for (Long i = 2L; i < num; i++) {
            resultado = (datos[0] + datos[1] + datos[2]) % 10000;
            datos[0] = datos[1];
            datos[1] = datos[2];
            datos[2] = resultado;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

o cambiando las condiciones y valor inicial del for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] datos = new int[] {
       1,2,3
    };
    Long num = 2020202020202020L % 124000L;
    int resultado = 0;
    if (num < 4) {
        resultado = datos[num.intValue()];
    } else {
        for (Long i = 3L; i < num; i++) {
            resultado = (datos[0] + datos[1] + datos[2]) % 10000;
            datos[0] = datos[1];
            datos[1] = datos[2];
            datos[2] = resultado;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

Con esta corrección el valor final es 1366.

Comment: Llevas toda la razón, a lo mejor debería leerme mejor el enunciado la próxima vez :D Luego lo edito y te doy crédito por darte cuenta.

Comment: Piensan que este ejercicio es un nivel jr o un poquito mas arriba?

Comment: Amigos, no logro comprender porque los resultados se repiten cada 124000, como sacaron esa cuenta?

Comment: @Gonzalo, se repite cuando los tres valores que se guardan en el resultado vuelven a ser 1, 2, 3. Si miras la edición que hice pone como comprobarlo. Si te han servido estas respuestas, por favor marca la respuesta de Matias como la aceptada, que es quién te ha dado con la solución correcta.

Comment: @Gonzalo, respecto a si es un nivel jr, no se muy bien con qué equipararlo, pero la verdad es que es ha sido un ejercicio interesante :-) Gracias por traérlo

Answer (score 4):

Un array en Java no puede tener un índice que sea long:

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become int values.
>
> An attempt to access an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time error.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4

Si necesitas albergar más datos que los que se pueden indexar con un integer, tendrás que usar alguna librería específica o generar tu propia estructura de datos donde encadenes valores.

También te deberías preguntar si tu aplicación se puede organizar de otra forma para que no se almacene en memoria principal una cantidad tan masiva de datos. (De hecho, no creo que te cupiese en memoria con un ordenador convencional de hoy en día)

Para este ejercicio concreto, me parece que se espera que calcules el resultado de otra manera, no reservando tantas posiciones de memoria.

Puedes calcular el mismo resultado guardando únicamente los tres últimos elementos:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] datos = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
        Long num = 2020202020202020L;
        int resultado = 0;
        if (num < 3) {
            resultado = datos[num.intValue()];
        } else {
            for (Long i = 2L; i < num; i++) {
                resultado = (datos[0] + datos[1] + datos[2]) % 10000;
                datos[0] = datos[1];
                datos[1] = datos[2];
                datos[2] = resultado;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
```

Lo que hace el programa es calcular el resultado para cada iteración sumando lo que haya en el array `datos`, que contiene siempre las tres últimas posiciones. Como de la suma nos interesan solo los últimos 4 dígitos, podemos realizar el módulo por 10000 cada vez que sumamos.

Después de calcular el resultado actual, se rota los valores del array de datos, poniendo en la primera posición lo que había en la segunda, poniendo en la segunda posición lo que había en la tercera, y poniendo en la tercera lo que acabamos de calcular.

Paciencia cuando lo ejecutes, porque el número de iteraciones es grandísimo.

EDIT: He estado dándole vueltas, y si lo piensas es posible que el ciclo se esté repitiendo varias veces si el array de resultado en algún momento vuelve a ser [1, 2, 3]. En el programa anterior he añadido esto:

```
if (datos[0] == 1 && datos[1] == 2 && datos[2] == 3) {
    System.out.println("Encontrado ciclo en: " + i);
    break;
}
```

Con esto he visto que los resultados se repiten cada 124000 iteraciones.
Es decir:

```
Para num = 0 -> resultado = 1
Para num = 1 -> resultado = 2
Para num = 2 -> resultado = 3

Para num = 124000 -> resultado = 1
Para num = 124000 -> resultado = 2
Para num = 124000 -> resultado = 3
```

Quiere decirse que no hay que iterar 2020202020202020L, nos basta iterar hasta 2020202020202020L % 124000L. El resultado es este código **(GRACIAS Matias Berettoni por la corrección)** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] datos = new int[] {
       1,2,3
    };
    Long num = 2020202020202020L % 124000L;
    int resultado = 0;
    if (num < 4) {
        resultado = datos[num.intValue()];
    } else {
        for (Long i = 3L; i < num; i++) {
            resultado = (datos[0] + datos[1] + datos[2]) % 10000;
            datos[0] = datos[1];
            datos[1] = datos[2];
            datos[2] = resultado;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

Al ejecutarlo, acaba inmediatamente y devuelve 1366.

Comment: Me parece muy buena solucion, porque en vez de recorrer todas las posiciones, solo recorres 3 variables. Excelente. Ahora, pensas que se podria utilizar otro tipo de clase o estructura de datos para optimizarlo?

Comment: @Gonzalo, he editado la respuesta, porque me he dado cuenta de que solo necesitas los últimos 4 dígitos. Si solo necesitas los 4 últimos dígitos, puedes hacer el módulo por 10000 cada vez que sumas, de tal manera que no necesitas BigDecimal, y te basta con un simple int. Esto debería agilizar también el cálculo, aún así son muchas iteraciones y te tardará.

Comment: de igual manera esta bien planteado como estaba antes, pensas que con colecciones o arraylist seria mas optimo el codigo?

Comment: No puedo probarlo con tiempos ahora mismo, pero me atrevería a decir que si trabajas con un array de 3 posiciones o una colección de 3 posiciones el tiempo debería ser más o menos el mismo, o algo peor con la colección. Si alguien se anima a probarlo y demostrar lo contrario, sería interesante para ver los datos obtenidos.

Comment: gracias @ordago!

Comment: @Gonzalo ¿ejecutaste el programa hasta el final? Por curiosidad, ¿cuáles son los últimos 4 dígitos?

Comment: Hola @orgado! No lo he probado con los ultimos 4 digitos, si no, tu resolucion anterior, pero se demora un montonazo...

Comment: muchas gracias! Un genio!

Answer (score 0):

A una PC actual le llevaría miles de años correr el programa sin tomar en cuenta las repeticiones. En un principio, uno infiere que en algún momento la secuencia se repite aunque no está seguro si logrará hacerlo antes de que la máquina se cuelgue. Por mi parte usé lenguaje Python y empecé con un while :

```
    while ciclos_no_def or ciclos>demasiados_ciclos: 
    # La segunda condición es una proteccion por si no se hallan repeticiones 
        ciclos+=1
        suma= sumar(lista)%10000 # Se utilizan solo los 4 últimos dígitos
        lista = ordenar(lista)
        if str(lista) in conj_listas: # Buscando si se repite la lista
            ciclos_no_def=False
        else:
            conj_listas= conj_listas+str(lista) # Actualiza el conjunto de 
    listas
```

lista es una var tipo "lista" de python que paso como argumento a las funciones sumar() y ordenar()
lista=[1,2,3]
Al no conocer cuántos ciclos llevará encontrar una coincidencia uso la var "demasiados_ciclos" (inicializada en p.ej 500000) para que ante la duda no se quede en un bucle infinito. Una vez encontrada la coincidencia, la variable contador "ciclos" me da cada cuánto se da esa coincidencia (124000 iteraciones). Con eso hago un  2020202020202020 % (mod) 124000 y con el resultado (102020) implemento un for para la última secuencia.
La salida la hago a un archivo ya que es demasiada info para analizarla por pantalla por un humano. 
El programa completo demora 49 segundos.